# Reference Request: Schauder theory for fourth-order parabolic equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am looking for a treatment of fourth order parabolic equations in Holder spaces. More precisely fourth order analogues of Theorems 5.1, 5.2, and 10.1 in Chapter IV of [Linear and quasilinear equations of parabolic type](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=241822). These are simply the parabolic Schauder estimates. To be more concrete I am only really concerned with IBVPs, roughly, of the following form:

$$\begin{align}
\partial_t u + \partial_x^4 u &= f \mbox{ for } (t,x) \in (0,T) \times (0,1), \\
u(0,x) &= u_0(x) \mbox{ for } x \in (0,1) \\
u(t,0) &= \partial_x u(t,0) = 0, \mbox{ and } \\
u(t,1) &= \partial_x u(t,1) = 0 \mbox{ for } t \in (0,T).
\end{align}$$

I have done some searching already but couldn't find anything close to what I needed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: On a formal level, you will need a bit more boundary conditions...

Answer (score 3):

I do not have access to the book you cite, but Section 3.2 in [Lunardi's book](http://books.google.hu/books?id=mWojiHzg9bEC&printsec=frontcover) contains a broad overview on higher order parabolic problems with lots of references, including the most important Hölder estimates.